# How to have all possibilities of path with specific beginning?

Tags: python, path, partition, os.path

I have to check a variable file at a location :

```
variable = "40014ee0aee34570"
os.path.realpath(/dev/disk/by-id/wwn-0x{0}'.format(variable))
```

I need to check if there is also `40014ee0aee34570-part1`, `40014ee0aee34570-part2` and etc.

For now I can do it like this

```
os.path.realpath('/dev/disk/by-id/wwn-0x{0}{1}'.format(variable, '-part1')
```

But how I can do check for every possibility number after part in this line programatically ?
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using `glob` module.

```
import glob

variable = "40014ee0aee34570"

# file wildcard, use * at the end to get all suffixes
file_wildcard = "/dev/disk/by-id/wwn-0x{0}*".format(variable)

possible_file_paths = glob.glob(file_wildcard)

for file_path in possible_file_paths:
    os.path.realpath(file_path)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply concatenate srtings with `+`

Example :

```
string1 = "I am "
string2 = "foo"
string3 = string1 + string2 
print(string3)

OUT[1]:
>> I am foo
```

Thus, you can use it to generate your path to your file programatically with all the components (root path , variable name, suffixes, numbers ,etc..) :

```
import os

path = r"/dev/disk/by-id/"

file_prefix = "wwn-0x"
variable = "40014ee0aee34570"
file_suffix = "-part"

for number in range(0,10):
  file = os.path.join(path , file_prefix  + variable  + file_suffix + str(number))
  if os.path.exists(file):
    print(f"{file} exists")
  else :
    print(f"no file with that part number {number}")
```

Comment: I made some corrections, there was some typos in the code